# replacing double pipes || in Pandas or Python

Tags: python, pandas

working through some badly thought out data which uses '||' as a delimiter within a single string. I had an excel file that is over 60 sheets and 100k individual records which has these '||' separating interests. for example:

```
email          interests  
info@test.com  Sports||IT||Business||Other
```

I've tried using the following code to replace the pipes but it doesn't seem to work.. are the pipes considered a special character? A google search yielded no Python specific results for me.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("test.xlsx")
df["interests"] = df["interests"].replace('||', ' , ')
```

using str.replace for some reason just adds in a load of commas between each individual character

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Series.replace(..., regex=False, ...)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) uses `regex=False` per default, which means it'll try to replace the whole cell value.

Demo:

```
In [25]: df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['ab ab', 'ab']})

In [26]: df
Out[26]:
     col
0  ab ab
1     ab

In [27]: df['col'].replace('ab', 'XXX')
Out[27]:
0    ab ab        # <--- NOTE!
1      XXX
Name: col, dtype: object

In [28]: df['col'].replace('ab', 'ZZZ', regex=True)
Out[28]:
0    ZZZ ZZZ
1        ZZZ
Name: col, dtype: object
```

So don't forget to use `regex=True` parameter:

```
In [23]: df["interests"] = df["interests"].replace('\|\|', ' , ', regex=True)

In [24]: df
Out[24]:
           email                       interests
0  info@test.com  Sports , IT , Business , Other
```

or use [Series.str.replace()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) which always treats it as RegEx:

```
df["interests"] = df["interests"].str.replace('\|\|', ' , ')
```

PS beside that [`|` is a special RegEx symbol](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html), which means `OR`, so we need to escape it with a back-slash character

Comment: you sir are a legend, worked perfectly, Could you explain where I went wrong? and what I was missing, why does the pipe need to be split with a \ ? will be back to green tick your answer!

Comment: My thanks to you good sir. Your explanation is succinct I hope it will benefit anyone else with the same problem.

Comment: @Datanovice, glad i could help :)